# Removing characters from string in R

Tags: r, string

I have some tabs or space breaks in my R output (I suspect the problem in the task from which the output comes), making it look like this:

```
[1841] "\t\t\tGreen\n\t\t"         
[1842] "Blue"                       
[1843] "\t\t\tRed\n\t\t"
```

For a colleague I have to read this into SPSS and that gives some trouble when reading this as txt data, so I wanted to remove the \t and \n parts in my string:

```
str_replace(mydata, "([\n])", "")
```

Tried it with both \n and \t or combinations, but never quite worked.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to use `str_replace_all` to remove the multiple accounts of whitespace characters. Why not use base R to remove these characters instead of loading the `stringr` package?

```
gsub('[\t\n]', '', mydata)
```

Answer (score 12):

Try

```
library(stringr)
str1 <- c("\t\t\tGreen\n\t\t", "Blue",  "\t\t\tRed\n\t\t" )
str_replace_all(str1, "([\n\t])", "")

#[1] "Green" "Blue"  "Red"
```

Or using `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
stri_replace_all_regex(str1, "[\n\t]", "")
#[1] "Green" "Blue"  "Red"
```

#### Update

Suppose, if there are multiple words in the string, the `gsub` and `str_replace_all` would provide the same output.

```
x <- c("\t\t\tGreen\n\t\t", "Blue", "\t\t\tRed\n\t\t yellow")
str_replace_all(x, '[\n\t]', '')
#[1] "Green"      "Blue"       "Red yellow"
```

Another option would be to use `strip` from `qdap`

```
library(qdap)
strip(x, lower.case=FALSE)
#[1] "Green"      "Blue"       "Red yellow"
## Or...
Trim(clean(x))
#[1] "Green"      "Blue"       "Red yellow"
```