# how to edit string in r?

Tags: r, string, stringr

Does anyone know how to manipulate a string in a way that will return just the values and omit the ", " that separates the characters?

```
string <- "a, ., z,  , a, n, f, r, a"
```

End result should be:

```
"a.z anfra"
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27044727/removing-characters-from-string-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stringr solution, essentially the same as Sirius'

```
library(stringr)
string <- "a, ., z,  , a, n, f, r, a"

str_remove_all(string = string, pattern = ", ")
[1] "a.z anfra"
```

Answer (score 1):

look at `sub`

something like:

```
gsub( ", ", "", string )
```